# Get() method returns the right value the first time while the second time returns null

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using a hash-map to store key value pairs. When I use the get method to retrieve an Identifier object key called "Ape", it correctly returns the Set object value "1,2,3,4" yet when I try to retrieve the same object the value returns "".

I have already tried making sure I wasn't somehow removing the value key pairs and checking if I am creating a new hashmap every time. When I print out the hashmap to string method, the Identifier object "Ape" is not longer in the map along with it's value.

Sorry for the large amounts of code! I wasn't sure whether to add it all or not.

```
package nl.vu.labs.phoenix.ap;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * A set interpreter for sets of elements of type T
 */
public class Interpreter<T extends SetInterface<BigInteger>> implements InterpreterInterface<T> {

    HashMap<IdentifierInterface, T> hm = new HashMap<IdentifierInterface, T>();
    @Override
    public T getMemory(String v) {
        IdentifierInterface i = new Identifier();
        i.appendIdentifier(v);
        if(hm.containsKey(i)){
            return hm.get(i);
        }else{

        return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T eval(String s) {
        System.out.println("HASHMAP:"+hm.toString());
        Scanner in;
        try {
            in = format(s);
        } catch (APException e1) {
            in=new Scanner(s);
        }
        in.useDelimiter("");
        try {
            readStatement(in);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
            char nextChar(Scanner in) {
                return in.next().charAt(0);
            }

            boolean nextCharIs(Scanner in, char c) {
                boolean IsMatch = in.hasNext(Pattern.quote(c+""));
                return IsMatch;
            }

            boolean nextCharIsDigit (Scanner in) {
                return in.hasNext("[0-9]");
            }

            boolean nextCharIsLetter (Scanner in) {
                return in.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]");
            }

            void eraseSpace(Scanner in) {
                while (nextCharIs(in, ' ')) {
                    nextChar(in);
                }
            }

            private void checkChar (String in, char a) throws APException {
                Scanner token = new Scanner(in);
                if (! nextCharIs(token, a)) {
                    throw new APException("Missing token: " + a);
                }

            }

            private String SetToString(SetInterface<BigInteger> set){
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

                if(set.first()){
                    output.append(set.get());

                    while(set.next()){
                        output.append(" ");
                        output.append(set.get());
                    }
                }
                return output.toString();
            }

            private Scanner format(String statement) throws APException {

                Scanner in = new Scanner(statement);
                in.useDelimiter("");
                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

                while (in.hasNext()) {

                    if (nextCharIs(in, '/')) {
                        line.append(in.nextLine());
                        return new Scanner(line.toString());
                    } else if (nextCharIsLetter(in) || nextCharIsDigit(in)) {
                        line.append(in.next());
                        while (nextCharIs(in, ' ')) {
                            checkChar(in.next(), ' ');

                            if (nextCharIsLetter(in) || nextCharIsDigit(in)) {
                                throw new APException("Identifier error: spaces inside identifier not allowed");
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (nextCharIs(in, ' ')) {
                        checkChar(in.next(), ' ');
                    } else {
                        line.append(in.next());
                    }
                }
                String formated = line.toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < formated.length(); i++) {
                    if (formated.charAt(i) == ',') {

                        try {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(formated.charAt(i - 1)) || !Character.isDigit(formated.charAt(i + 1))) {
                                throw new APException("no number in set");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new APException("no number in set");
                        }
                    } else if (formated.charAt(i) == '0') {
                        if (!Character.isDigit(formated.charAt(i - 1)) && Character.isDigit(formated.charAt(i + 1))) {
                            throw new APException("Invalid number");
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new Scanner(line.toString());
            }
            void readStatement(Scanner in)throws APException{

                if (nextCharIsLetter(in)) {

                    readAssignment(in);

                } else if (nextCharIs(in, '?')) {
                    readPrint_statement(in);

                } else if (! nextCharIs(in, '/')){
                    throw new APException("Invalid statement, please read the documentation");
                }
            }

            void readAssignment(Scanner in) throws APException{
                //handle end of line

                in.useDelimiter("=");
                IdentifierInterface i;
                SetInterface<BigInteger> set;
                i=readIdentifier(in);
                set = readExpression(new Scanner(in.next()));
                this.hm.put(i,(T)set);



            }
            void readPrint_statement(Scanner in)throws APException{
                in.useDelimiter("");
                if(nextCharIs(in,'(')||nextCharIs(in,'{')||nextCharIsLetter(in)||nextCharIsDigit(in)){
                    readExpression(in);

                }else if (! nextCharIs(in, ';')){
                    throw new APException("Invalid statement, please read the documentation");
                }
            }

            IdentifierInterface readIdentifier(Scanner in)throws APException{

                  IdentifierInterface i = new Identifier();
                  String ident="";
                  if(in.hasNext()) {
                      ident+=in.next();

                  }
                  System.out.println("readident:"+ident);
                  i.appendIdentifier(ident);
                  if(i.hasCorrectIdentifierFormat(i.toString())){
                      return i;
                  }else{
                      throw new APException("Invalid Identifier foramt");
                  }

            }
            SetInterface<BigInteger> readExpression(Scanner in)throws APException{
                in.useDelimiter("");
                SetInterface<BigInteger> term = null;
                StringBuilder terms = new StringBuilder();
                while (in.hasNext()) {

                    while(nextCharIs(in, ' ')) {
                        in.next();
                    }
                    //System.out.println("HRE:"+in.next());
                    if (nextCharIs(in, '+') || nextCharIs(in, '-') || nextCharIs(in, '|')) {
                        String addOp = in.next();

                        if (term == null) {
                            term = readTerm(new Scanner(terms.toString()));

                        }
                        terms.setLength(0);

                        while (in.hasNext()) {

                            if ((nextCharIs(in, '+') || nextCharIs(in, '-') || nextCharIs(in, '|'))) {
                                term = addOps(term, readTerm(new Scanner(terms.toString())), addOp);
                                terms.setLength(0);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                terms.append(in.next());
                            }
                        }
                        if (terms != null) {
                            term = addOps(term, readTerm(new Scanner(terms.toString())), addOp);
                        }
                    } else {

                        terms.append(in.next());

                    }
                }

                if (term == null) {
                    term = readTerm(new Scanner(terms.toString()));

            }

                return term;
            }
            SetInterface<BigInteger> addOps(SetInterface<BigInteger> set1, SetInterface<BigInteger> set2, String op){
                System.out.print("addops");
                SetInterface<BigInteger> set = new Set<>();
                if(op=="+"){
                    set = set1.union(set2);
                }else if(op=="-"){
                    set = set1.difference(set2);    
                }else{
                    set = set1.symmetricDifference(set2);
                }
                return set;
            }


            SetInterface<BigInteger> readTerm(Scanner in)throws APException{
                in.useDelimiter("");
                SetInterface<BigInteger> factor;
                StringBuilder factors = new StringBuilder();


                while (in.hasNext()) {

                    if (nextCharIs(in, '*')) {
                        checkChar(in.next(), '*');
                        factor = readFactor(new Scanner(factors.toString())).intersection(readTerm(new Scanner(in.nextLine())));
                        return factor;
                    } else {
                        factors.append(in.next());
                    }
                }

                factor = readFactor(new Scanner(factors.toString()));
                return factor;
            }
            SetInterface<BigInteger> readFactor(Scanner in)throws APException{
                in.useDelimiter("");
                SetInterface<BigInteger> resultset = new Set<>();
                int complexFactors = 0;
                StringBuilder sets = new StringBuilder();

                while(in.hasNext()) {
                    if(nextCharIs(in,' ')){
                        in.next();
                    }
                    if (nextCharIs(in, '(')) {
                        checkChar(in.next(), '(');
                        complexFactors += 1;
                        while (in.hasNext() && complexFactors != 0) {

                            if (nextCharIs(in, '(')) {
                                complexFactors += 1;

                                sets.append(in.next());
                            } else if (nextCharIs(in, ')')) {

                                complexFactors -= 1;
                                sets.append(in.next());
                                if (complexFactors == 0) {
                                    if (nextCharIs(in,')')) {

                                        throw new APException("Invalid token detected");
                                    }
                                } else {

                                    if(!in.hasNext()&&complexFactors!=0){

                                        throw new APException("Invalid token detected");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                    sets.append(in.next());
                                    }
                                }
                            }else {
                                sets.append(in.next());
                            }
                        }
                        resultset = readExpression(new Scanner(sets.toString()));
                    } else if (nextCharIsLetter(in)) {
                        sets.append(in.next());

                        while (nextCharIsLetter(in)|| nextCharIsDigit(in)) {
                            sets.append(in.next());
                        }
                        IdentifierInterface i = new Identifier();
                        i.appendIdentifier(sets.toString());

                        if (hm.containsKey(i)) {
                            resultset = hm.get(i);
                            return resultset;
                        } else {
                            throw new APException("Identifier \\\""+ sets.toString() +"\\\" does not correspond to a sets");
                        }
                    } 
                    if (nextCharIs(in,'{')) {

                        checkChar(in.next(), '{');
                        if (nextCharIs(in,',')) {
                            throw new APException("no number");
                        }

                        while (!nextCharIs(in,'}') && in.hasNext()) {
                            sets.append(in.next());
                        }

                        if (in.hasNext()) {
                            checkChar(in.next(), '}');
                        } else {
                            throw new APException("Invalid token");
                        }

                        if (in.hasNext()) {
                            throw new APException("Operator or end of line missing");
                        }
                        resultset = readSet(sets.toString());
                    } else {
                        throw new APException("Invalid statement detected");
                    }
                }
                if (complexFactors != 0) {
                    throw new APException("Missing parenthesis detected");
                }

                return resultset;
            }

            SetInterface<BigInteger> readSet(String nums)throws APException{
                SetInterface<BigInteger> set = new Set<>();
                Scanner in = new Scanner(nums);
                in.useDelimiter(",");
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        set.add(in.nextBigInteger());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new APException("Invalid number detected in a set");
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                //set.fixDoubles();
                return set;
            }


}

public void parenthesisBalanceTests() {
        InterpreterInterface<Set<BigInteger>> interpreter = new Interpreter<Set<BigInteger>>();

        interpreter.eval("Ape = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}");
        // missing closing parenthesis test
        interpreter.eval("Ape = (({1, 2, 3})");

        SetInterface<BigInteger> actual = interpreter.getMemory("Ape");
        System.out.print("ACTRUAL:"+actual);
        ArrayList<BigInteger> expected = convertExpectedList("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
        assertTrue("missing closing parenthesis' should result in an exception", compareSets(actual, expected));

        // missing opening parenthesis test
        interpreter.eval("Ape = ({1, 2, 3}))");
        actual = interpreter.getMemory("Ape");
        assertTrue("missing opening parenthesis' should result in an exception", compareSets(actual, expected));
    }
```

These are the tests I am supposed to pass in parenthesisBalcenceTest(). Missing closing parenthesis test passes because actual returns "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", but missing opening parenthesis fails because actual is "".

Comment: It's not easy to follow the code as several of those classes aren't defined in what you posted (`SetInterface`, `InterpreterInterface`, etc.) but one thought is that you're maybe overwriting values in the HashMap with this line: `this.hm.put(i,(T)set);`. You could add a `println()` statement above – print out whatever the new `set` is, see if it's null sometimes.

Comment: How `equal`and `hashCode` are implemented in `IdentifierInterface` class?

Comment: Please show `IdentifierInterface` code. As @Mateusz points out, every class that is to be the key of a `Map` in Java **must** implement the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) and `equals` method *consistently*.